# Possible Force To Https And Http (Laravel Project)

Tags: php, laravel

I created laravel project and the project already configure the `SSL Certificate` to the server.

**Laravel Version 5.6**

This is the possible way that i use already to force https however i wont work to me,

```
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.hiflyer.ca/$1 [R,L]

    //=====//

     if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
        \URL::forceScheme('https');
     }

  //======//

  APP_URL = https://hiflyer.ca
```

I used to `APP_URL` to force `https` it works, however when i type in (INCOGNITO)
http://hiflyer.ca/ the browser gives me error You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Where should i configure to access both `HTTP` and `HTTPS`

Comment: do you have an `http://hiflyer.ca/` at `<VirtualHost *:80>` along with your `https`?.

Comment: I don't know . @gil because i don't have access to the server.. my system admin knows everything to that

Comment: Are you using XAMPP or WAMP/LAMP? You can just edit the *httpd-vhosts.conf* file in its directory. I thought its your project however if you don't have access to the computer (server) that's a big problem.

Comment: @gil i already configure but when i type without www  only hiflyer.ca it says forbidden permission

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an Apache thing (as you are using Apache).  It seems you have the forcing routes code correct - so try the following in your site configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName hiflyer.ca
Redirect permanent / https://hiflyer.ca/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i configure this to my server?

Comment: Yes - you will create your config in sites-available in Apache.  You will need to ensure that you have your SSL configured below this - it seems you do already have this setup correctly however.  So you can use Aritsan serve locally and not worry about SSL and not have this baked into your code / other configs.

Comment: thank you for helping me, however when i type hiflyer.ca i dont have access but when i use www.hiflyer.ca the site is working. then if i click to the navigations. all the routes not working

Comment: No problem.  When I type in hiflyer.ca it redirects me to https: and I can see the website.  If you want to redirect to www just prepend www to the redirect.